# How do I sort through lines of a text document to find a phrase based on a date?

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting, date, text-files

I am writing a program that logs jobs into a file and then sorts and organises the jobs by date. The entries are lists that are just appended to the end of a text file. They appear in the file like so:

```
2017-01-31,2016-05-24,test1
2016-05-15,2016-05-24,test2
2016-06-15,2016-05-24,test3
2016-07-16,2016-05-24,test4
```

They follow this format: due date, date entered, job title. I would like to be able to be able to print the jobs from the text file to the python shell by order of dates, the job with the closest date being first. I was thinking of turning each line into an item in a list, doing something with the due date characters, and sorting that way. I can't figure out how to keep everything together if I do it that way though. Any thoughts?

Comment: which date are you sorting by, the earliest "finish" date or the earliest "start" date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the date strings into datetime objects. Then just sort the list of jobs by date and output them.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
jobs = []

with open('jobs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        date_due, date_entered, title = line.split(',')
        jobs.append((datetime.strptime(date_due, date_str_format),
                     datetime.strptime(date_entered, date_str_format),
                     title.strip()))

jobs.sort()

for date_due, _, title in jobs:
    print '{} (due {})'.format(title, date_due)
```

Here are the contents of `jobs.txt`:

```
2017-01-31,2016-05-24,test1
2016-05-15,2016-05-24,test2
2016-06-15,2016-05-24,test3
2016-07-16,2016-05-24,test4
```

And the output...

```
test2 (due 2016-05-15 00:00:00)
test3 (due 2016-06-15 00:00:00)
test4 (due 2016-07-16 00:00:00)
test1 (due 2017-01-31 00:00:00)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want since you've picked a nice date format:

```
lines = """
2017-01-31,2016-05-24,test1
2016-05-15,2016-05-24,test2
2016-06-15,2016-05-24,test3
2016-07-16,2016-05-24,test4
"""

sorted([entry.split(",") for entry in lines.split("\n") if any(entry)], reverse=True)
```

In Python 2.7 shell:

```
>>> lines = """
... 2017-01-31,2016-05-24,test1
... 2016-05-15,2016-05-24,test2
... 2016-06-15,2016-05-24,test3
... 2016-07-16,2016-05-24,test4
... """
>>> 
>>> lines_sorted = sorted([entry.split(",") for entry in lines.split("\n") if any(entry)], reverse=True)
>>> for line in lines_sorted:
...     print line
... 
['2017-01-31', '2016-05-24', 'test1']
['2016-07-16', '2016-05-24', 'test4']
['2016-06-15', '2016-05-24', 'test3']
['2016-05-15', '2016-05-24', 'test2']
>>>
```

Using string formatting and unpacking using `*`:

```
output_str = "Due date: {0}\nDate entered: {1}\nJob title: {2}\n"

entries_sorted = sorted([entry.split(",") for entry in lines.split("\n") if any(entry)], reverse=True)
for entry in entries_sorted:
    print output_str.format(*entry)
```

Output:

```
Due date: 2017-01-31
Date entered: 2016-05-24
Job title: test1

Due date: 2016-07-16
Date entered: 2016-05-24
Job title: test4

Due date: 2016-06-15
Date entered: 2016-05-24
Job title: test3

Due date: 2016-05-15
Date entered: 2016-05-24
Job title: test2
```